# Python regex finding no matches

Tags: python, regex

I have the following file which I am trying to extract the date from `20131013.csv`

Using the regex `(?P<yyyy>\\d{4})(?P<mm>\\d{2})(?P<dd>\\d{2})`

```
def getEffectiveDate(regex, fileName) :
    parts = 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    formatString = '%s-%s-%s 00:00:00'
    regexGroups = parts.split("-")
    m = re.search(regex, fileName)
    if m :
        vals = []
        for regexGroup in regexGroups :
            vals.append(m.group(regexGroup))
        value = formatString%tuple(vals)
    return value
```

when I pass in`getEffectiveDate('(?P<yyyy>\\d{4})(?P<mm>\\d{2})(?P<dd>\\d{2})', '20131013.csv')` I don't find any matches.

However the regex `(?P<yyyy>\\d{4})-(?P<mm>\\d{2})-(?P<dd>\\d{2})` will find a match on `2013-10-13.csv`

I am wondering if this is being caused by there being nothing inbetween the regex groups and if there is anything I can do to fix this?

EDIT:

I found a solution by doing `regex.replace('\\\\', '\\')`

The double backslashes were causing an issue with matching. I had only tried the regex `(?P<yyyy>\\d{4})-(?P<mm>\\d{2})-(?P<dd>\\d{2})` as a raw string so it was working in that case.

Comment: Your code  works for me..

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me. And it's better to define the regex as raw string.

```
>>> re.search(r'(?P<yyyy>\d{4})(?P<mm>\d{2})(?P<dd>\d{2})', '20131013.csv')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 8), match='20131013'>
>>> re.search(r'(?P<yyyy>\d{4})(?P<mm>\d{2})(?P<dd>\d{2})', '20131013.csv').group(1)
'2013'
>>> re.search(r'(?P<yyyy>\d{4})(?P<mm>\d{2})(?P<dd>\d{2})', '20131013.csv').group(2)
'10'
>>> re.search(r'(?P<yyyy>\d{4})(?P<mm>\d{2})(?P<dd>\d{2})', '20131013.csv').group(3)
'13'
```

Comment: How would I do that when this code is in a function that is being passed two variables  `getDate(regex, fileName)` and then I do `re.search(regex, fileName)`

Comment: @MrSnare edit your question with a clear cut explanation. . First compile the regex through `regex = re.compile(r'....')` then do `regex.search(filename)`